# react-select placeholder value showing outside the box

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to use react-select for a multi select dropdown use case. The issue I'm facing is that the placeholder displays over the select box rather than inside it.

[image]

Also, when I click, the options do not show properly.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div className="container">
<Row>
    <Col md={3}>
        <Select
            autosize={false}
            closeOnSelect={false}
            multi
            onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
            placeholder="More options"
            removeSelected={true}
            simpleValue
            value={this.state.selectedOptions}
            options={selectOptions}
        />
    </Col>
</Row>
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to add the react-select css. In my defence, I've started web development just 2 weeks back.

Cheers!